# Filtering dataframe dates based on dates in another dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, join, pyspark, filter

```
df_1 = 

scope      letter            date
  000         ABC      2022-07-01
  100         ABC      2022-08-01
  101         DEF      2022-08-02
  102         CCC      2022-08-15
  103         ABC      2022-08-16
  104         ABC      2022-08-31
  105         CCC      2022-09-01
  106         DEF      2022-09-02

df_2 =

  letter               date
     ABC         2022-08-01
     DEF         2022-08-02
     CCC         2022-09-02
```

How do I drop the rows in `df_1` for which the `date` is **later** than the date in `df_2`? I would expect:

```
df_1_new = 

scope      letter            date
  000         ABC      2022-07-01
  100         ABC      2022-08-01
  101         DEF      2022-08-02
  102         CCC      2022-08-15
  105         CCC      2022-09-01
```

I did a join, but it drops earlier dates too, which I do not want. Is it possible to do a join and then write an if-statement? Or is a join avoidable?

Comment: you [`join`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join) on letter and [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.filter) on the date condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Semi Join`.

```py
df_1_new = df_1.join(
    df_2, [df_1["letter"] == df_2["letter"], df_1["date"] <= df_2["date"]], how="semi"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever possible, I would avoid using symbols `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=` inside `join` conditions, because in some cases it could generate a `BroadcastNestedLoopJoin` - a cross join which would drag the performance.

Inputs:

```py
df_1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("000", "ABC", "2022-07-01"),
        ("100", "ABC", "2022-08-01"),
        ("101", "DEF", "2022-08-02"),
        ("102", "CCC", "2022-08-15"),
        ("103", "ABC", "2022-08-16"),
        ("104", "ABC", "2022-08-31"),
        ("105", "CCC", "2022-09-01"),
        ("106", "DEF", "2022-09-02"),
    ],
    ["scope", "letter", "date"],
)
df_2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("ABC", "2022-08-01"), ("DEF", "2022-08-02"), ("CCC", "2022-09-02")],
    ["letter", "date"],
)
```

Script:

```py
df_1_new = (
    df_1.join(df_2.withColumnRenamed("date", "date2"), "letter", "left")
    .filter("date <= date2")
    .select(df_1["*"])
)

df_1_new.show()
# +-----+------+----------+
# |scope|letter|      date|
# +-----+------+----------+
# |  000|   ABC|2022-07-01|
# |  100|   ABC|2022-08-01|
# |  102|   CCC|2022-08-15|
# |  105|   CCC|2022-09-01|
# |  101|   DEF|2022-08-02|
# +-----+------+----------+
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

```
df_1['max'] = df_1['letter'].map(df_2.set_index('letter').to_dict()['date'])
df_1_new = df_1[df_1.date <= df_1['max']].drop(columns='max')
```

Comment: I think OP needs an anwser in PySpark, not Pandas

Answer (score -2):

So first we make a dictionary of `df_2` for easy/fast comparison

```py
d = dict(zip(df_2.letter, df_2.date))
d

{
    "ABC": Timestamp("2022-08-01 00:00:00"),
    "DEF": Timestamp("2022-08-02 00:00:00"),
    "CCC": Timestamp("2022-09-02 00:00:00"),
}
```

Next we select rows from `df_1` that are confirming to the condition

```py
df_1[df_1.apply(lambda x: False if x.date < d[x.letter] else True, axis=1)]
```

```
    scope   letter  date
1   100     ABC     2022-08-01
2   101     DEF     2022-08-02
4   103     ABC     2022-08-16
5   104     ABC     2022-08-31
7   106     DEF     2022-09-02
```

Comment: Regarding the tags, I think OP needs an anwser in PySpark, not Pandas

Comment: That solution is not scallable

Comment: I think they wanted to avoid joins. and this is without joins. Btw, what scalability issue do you see? @Steven

Comment: This solution is avoiding joins but it's not working with PySpark. There is no `apply` method available in PySpark. In addition, you cannot transform a pyspark dataframe directly to a dict.